# No autocomplete options in body of #else

Tags: objective-c, xcode, autocomplete, preprocessor-directive

At the top of my class I've defined a flag:

```
#define CarsRandom
```

Then later in one of my methods I declare a static `int` and a `float`. Then I want to check to see if `CarsRandom` is defined and act accordingly:

```
#ifdef CarsRandom
  //Everything is accesible in this part
#else
  //Even NSLog is not accessible
#endif
```

The problem is that in the `#else` part, the variables that are declared at the beginning of the method are not accesible via autocomplete. Though I can build the project successfully, I wonder why even `NSLog()` is not present in the autocomplete list.

Comment: Are you aware that you are using compiler-directives? Perhaps an ordinary if-statement would be better?

Comment: Sure I do, I just needed to put a flag so that when I just comment that directive out I get a different result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IDE, presumably XCode, is trying to be clever and failing.

It notices that the piece of code inside the else won't be compiled, so tries to ignore it completely, even to the point of ignoring auto complete.

Perhaps you could write it as a normal if, else while testing and rewrite later if you would like that code to be compiled out for production.